# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzbq.class

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am new in Android. i am currently working in android app and when i try to run the app this error occurs.

I  have researched but cant solve this error.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fex60.png)

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
    applicationId "com.tutorialsbuzz.androidfacebook"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
}
```

thankyou in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason behind that may be you have include two different versions for gms. Also if you have included the complete package then there is no need to include the second 'compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'' If you need only auth services from google then dont include the complete package it ll exceed 65k methods and duplicacy chances will be there. 
Include this

> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'

and from your code remove

> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1' compile
>   'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'

Execute it and let me know once.

Answer (score 10):

In my case, it's because of the

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.+'
```

I change it to this:

```
 compile ('com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.+'){
        exclude group:"com.google.android.gms"
    }
```

No more problem!

Comment: Thanks a lot brother. I was trying to solve it from last 2 days.

Comment: Neat trick! This was it for me, except on the `firebase-ads` module I was adding.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Firebase, you should read my solution. In my case I developed a new app. This new app has ads, so I put `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.0.4'` BEFORE `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'`.

But either you have to put everything AFTER `firebase-core` or it's about the version number `11.0.4` that have to be the same on all firebase modules you are using.

Comment: this works....make sure your core is in compile first and then others....

Answer (score 0):

Excluding `com.google.android.gms` from the offending package worked to build the project for me, but unfortunately the app would crash during initialization. The solution for me was to upgrade all `firebase` dependencies from `11.6.0` to `11.8.0`, ie:

```
- compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.0"
- compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.0"
- compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.0"
- compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:11.6.0"
- compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.6.0"

+ compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0"
+ compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0"
+ compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0"
+ compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:11.8.0"
+ compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.8.0"
```

The problem was only presenting itself when adding `firebase-ads` but this fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Please be sure that you are using **identical** versions of `com.google.gms`. 
You can run the next command from the project root dir to find out which versions are used:

```
./gradlew :<subproject>:dependencies
```

Usually it is something like this:

```
./gradlew :app:dependencies
```

After analyzing you are able to set the same versions or `exclude` group from some modules or expose a version