# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. > error

Tags: android

Please help me to find a solution on this error.. When I build my project I got an error like this

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzbq.class
```

Please check ones my build.gradle(App level) file... Please give me a hint to move farword

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.realmilk.app.new"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 6
        versionName "1.0.6"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':volley')
    compile project(':materialviewpager')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'io.github.yavski:fab-speed-dial:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.jaredrummler:material-spinner:1.0.5'
    compile 'it.neokree:MaterialTabs:0.11'
    compile 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.+@aar'
    compile 'me.tatarka.support:jobscheduler:0.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Please give me your valuable suggestions... Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzbq.class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39490131/java-util-zip-zipexception-duplicate-entry-com-google-android-gms-internal-zzb)

Comment: remove this dependency compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'

Answer (score 0):

You are using 2 different versions of play service.

Change

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.1.0'
```

to

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.2.1'
```

So that both the auth and analytics service have same versions.

Similar question.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38201741/3111083.