# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzasq.class

Tags: android, google-play-services

Today I upgrade google play services from 10.0.1 to 10.2.0. When try to run my app, I get this error.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForClientDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzasq.class
```

Thanks

Comment: Because at least 2 libraries contain and use that `com/google/android/gms/internal/zzasq.class` so you have to check for yourself and remove 1.

Comment: This seems to be the same with this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39490131/java-util-zip-zipexception-duplicate-entry-com-google-android-gms-internal-zzb) and has been resolved.