# Building an APK generates Error:Execution failed for task

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

When I try to build with my current gradle.build file, I get an error, then following that my gradle build.

Why is it causing this error?

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzaf$zzd.class
```

this is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.usmans.videodownloader"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

}

dependencies {

androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

// glide
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.11.0'


compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'

compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.+'

compile 'com.io.tools.android.ramiloif.folderchooser:folderchooser-dialog:1.0.6'
```

I don't know what is causing this. What can I do to solve this issue?

Comment: Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44733976/5308778)

Answer (score 0):

Change and exclude gms from facebook library.

```
compile ('com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.+'){
        exclude group:"com.google.android.gms"
    }
```

Then clean and rebuild your project.

Hope it works :)